# remove null values in hive table

Tags: hive, null

removing blank values in hive table

table is like below

```
col1    col2     col3   col4
post1    -         -    G06
post1    -        F05    -
post1    H65       -     -
post2    J60       -     -
post2    -        K40    -
post2    -      -       M43
```

the output should be like below.

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
post1  H65     F05    G06
post2  J60     K40    M43
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `min()` or `max()` aggregation:

```
select col1, max(col2) col2, max(col3) col3, max(col4) col4 
  from table 
 group by col1;
```

Comment: `max` would be a lot safer. Nulls get represented in some funky ways in hive, including `?`, which typically will be "smaller" than any legitimate values.

Comment: @Andrew makes sense